# How to get java webstart 6 on OSX 10.8.2 after java update

Tags: macos, java, java-web-start

I'm trying to find out how to run java webstart 1.6 on a machine running OSX 10.8.2. Every time I try to open the .jnlp file I get java 7 rather than java 6 starting.

The system seems to still have java 6 installed:

```
java -version                                            
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)
```

However the java control panel shows only Java 7u9 (the latest update).